# total measure mondrian mdx

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

mdx newbie. I need your help with something that seems very simple. Below I have 1 dimension (Department) and 2 measures (Actual and Total).I want to define the Total measure without using any refference for the Department dimension. In this case. when I change my Department dimension with the Position dimension, the Total measure will still work.Because I use mondrian mdx I don't have the Axis() function.
How can I do this?

```
Department   Actual    Total
 /IT           150       450
 /Sales        150       450
 /Marketing    100       450
 /Legal        50        450
```

.

```
  WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Total] AS ................
  SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Actual], [Measures].[Total]} ON COLUMNS ,
  NON EMPTY {[Department].[Department].Members} ON ROWS
  FROM [Quadrant Analysis]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following calculated member:

```
With member [Measures].[Total] as Aggregate( [Department].[Department].Members, [Measures].[Actual] )
```

Comment: Hi, the result is correct but, like I said, I don't want to make any refference to the Department dimension

Comment: You need to refer to it at least once on your query! You can define a set called ROWSET first and use it on the calculated measure definition